# Able to access data through pyodbc and SELECT statements, but no new tables show up in SQL

Tags: sql-server, python-3.x, pyodbc

I have the following code which is working with no errors and returning the expected output when I print the results of the pyodbc cursor I created.

```py
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(MY_URL)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute(
    '''
    CREATE TABLE tablename(
        filename VARCHAR(100),
        synopsis TEXT,
        abstract TEXT,
        original TEXT,
        PRIMARY KEY (filename)
    )
    '''
)
for file in file_names_1:
    try:
        query = produce_row_query(file, tablename, find_tag_XML)
        cursor.execute(query)
    except pyodbc.DatabaseError as p:
        print(p)

result = cursor.execute(
    '''
    SELECT filename, 
    DATALENGTH(synopsis), 
    DATALENGTH(abstract), 
    original
    FROM ml_files
    '''
)

for row in cursor.fetchall():
    print(row)
```

However, no new tables are showing up in my actual MS SQL server. Am I missing a step to push the changes or something of that nature?

Comment: Did you specify a target database?

Comment: Side note - NO ONE should be using the text datatype.

Answer (score 1):

You need to commit changes or else they will not be updated in your actual database.

```
cnxn.commit()
```